# How to extract a certain value from JSON onto a map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

I have an array of maps with several values that I need to discard while keeping the map format.

I've played with the Arrays.map() function, but I only get to reach an array of values, without the map anymore.

The code would be:

```
x=[{"id":1, "name":"Bob"}, {"id":2, "name":"Sam"}, {"id":3, "name":"Lucy"}];
```

And the expected result I need is:

```
result=[{"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3}]
```

What I tried:

```
>> result= x.map(x => x.id);
<< result = [1, 2, 3]
```

I am sure this must be extremely straightforward, but I'm struggling to pull this one off, can I get some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your approach, you're extracting the id value, however, you're not generating `key-value` objects.

You can use the function `map` and destructuring the param in order to extract the `id` value.

```js
let x=[{"id":1, "name":"Bob"}, {"id":2, "name":"Sam"}, {"id":3, "name":"Lucy"}];
let result = x.map(({id}) => ({id}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```